# Correct syntax for database inserts from plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm testing a script to create a database insert. Is this the correct syntax for the insert or do I need to obtain a reference to global $wpdb and use that?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test Database Insert
*/

function test_db_insert()
{
INSERT wp_terms(term_id, 'name', slug) VALUES (1, 'test', 'test');
INSERT wp_term_taxonomy(term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, parent) VALUES (1, 1, 'category', 0);
INSERT wp_term_relationships(object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) VALUES (1, 1, 0);
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'test_db_insert');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like raw SQL that won't make sense to PHP at all.

You can run this queries, as raw queries using `$wpdb->query()` but it's more proper to use its `$wpdb->insert()` method.

See [wpdb Class > INSERT rows](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_rows) in Codex.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use SQL at all for that. Replace it with:

```
wp_set_object_terms(1, 'test', 'taxonomy_name');
```

…where `taxonomy_name` is the name of the taxonomy.

Comment: Seems to be the simplest, but I'm not sure it will do exactly what I want. Can I define the term_id of the new term (assuming it does not already exist)?

Comment: No but — at the risk of sounding glib! — why would you want to? Surely all that matters is that the ID is unique, since it's never actually seen by anyone?

Comment: I'm keying off cat_id = 1 to hide the uncategorized and all its children, since i use these for a specific purpose.